# How can I run ios App on real device via OSX shell command not using instruments?

Tags: ios, macos

I want to start ios App on real-ios-device in OSX - shellcommand.

How can I do this not using instruments?

for example. .. $> runIosApp -u 821381u2adsu3jakd test.CalendarApp.

Comment: I think you can do this using Xcodebuild with install and destination args. Unfortunately the doco's not great in this area and I don't have an example I can put as an answer. A little digging should get the info you need.

Comment: FYI - here's some example work on xcodebuild :) http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/xcodebuild-destination-options/

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap made a set of tools to do this. You can find information on how to use it here: https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy